# when i have , end = "" it wont work but when its removed i cant finish it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

[link to my program the problem is on line 122](https://repl.it/join/nndlpohr-alexmiranda)

I'm trying to add multiple parts of a list into a str but when I try it doesn't work and when I remove it I can't win the game

```
Chosen_word = "a"
winword = ""

dashlist = []
for i in range(len(Chosen_word)):
  dashlist.append("_ ")

  


for i in range(len(dashlist)):
  winword = dashlist[i], end = ""
if winword == Chosen_word:
  game = 1
```

This is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 140, in <module>
    win()
  File "main.py", line 122, in win
    winword = dashlist[i], end = ""
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Comment: please copy the code snippet where you are facing trouble here.

Comment: Also, saying "it doesn't work" is no help at all.  Instead, tell us what the code _does_ do, and how that's different from what you _wanted_.

Comment: I can't even begin to guess what you want the code to do.

Comment: why do you use `end = ""` ? assigning doesn't work like `print(..., end = "")`

Comment: oh i just want to be able to add more of the dashlist to it without overwriting the previous part of the list

Comment: if you want to add two strings then use `+` - ie. `"Hello" + " World"`  or apped to other string `winword += "Hello"`. If you want to concatenate all strings from list then do `winword = "".join( dashlist )` (without `for`-loop). BTW: you could learn to use `for word in dashlist: print(word)` instead  of `for i in range(len(dashlist)): print( dashlist[i[ )` - it is more readable.

Comment: if you want to add without overwriting then use `+=`  - like `winword += dashlist[i]` or in longer way `winword = winword + dashlist[i]`

Comment: thanks for the help now i can finish my program

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add (concatenate) string to other string then you should use `+` or `+=`

```
for i in range(len(dashlist)):
    winword = windword + dashlist[i]
```

or

```
for i in range(len(dashlist)):
    winword += dashlist[i]
```

You could also learn to use `for`-loop without `range(len())`

```
for item in dashlist:
    winword += item
```

You can also concatenate all strings on list using `join()` - and it doesn't need `for`-loop

```
winword = "".join( dashlist )
```

you can use it to add spaces between items

```
winword = " ".join( dashlist )
```

or commas

```
winword = ",".join( dashlist )
```

and then you don't have to use spaces in strings on this list.

```
dashlist.append("_")
```